# Show/hide control based on dropdown selection mvc 4 razor c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(z => z.SelectedReportId, new SelectList(Model.ReportTypes, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedReportId), "-- Select Report --")
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IncludePhotos)@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IncludePhotos)
```

Which generates:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SelectedReportId must be a number." data-val-required="The SelectedReportId field is required." id="SelectedReportId" name="SelectedReportId">
    <option value="">-- Select Report --</option>
    <option value="1">Excel Report</option>
    <option value="2">Text Report</option>
</select>
<br />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Include photos in the report field is required." id="IncludePhotos" name="IncludePhotos" type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

I have one dropdown and a checkbox, I need to disable the checkbox if the user selects the first value in dropdown. 
Here is the javascript I am using without success

```
$(function () {
    $('#SelectedReportId').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == '1') {
            $('#IncludePhotos').show();
        } else {
            $('#IncludePhotos').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: Can you show the HTML that the razor code is actually generating?

Comment: What is your JavaScript doing, if anything?

Comment: In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ccLpbps0/) everything looks ok. Are you getting script errors on the page? Are you sure jQuery is included properly?

Comment: I just realized that I am not actually calling the javascript function from anywhere!! In asp.net we use onclientclick="", how do I call the function in razor??

Comment: You don't need to explicitly call any function to run the `change` event handler (other than jQuery to register the event handler, which you're already calling)

Comment: How do I make sure that I register the event handler with jQuery?

Comment: In your code, the JavaScript between `$(function () { ... })` is called on `document.ready`. As long as it's in a `<script>` tag (usually in the `head` or `body` elements) it should get run on page load. The code inside of the `$(...)` attaches the event handler by selecting the `select` and attaching and event handler to the `change` event

Comment: I am stumped, not sure why this is not working then, everything looks okay

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors on the page

Comment: Mope, the page doesn't throw any js errors, however the javascript is right at the end of the form when I check the source <script language="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#SelectedReportId').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == '1') {
                $('#IncludePhotos').show();
            } else {
                $('#IncludePhotos').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</form>

Comment: it should be `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>`

Comment: changed it, now i get an error javascript $ is undefined

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere -- that means that jQuery is not included correctly on the page

Comment: How can I check the jquery and include it properly?

Comment: Got it, included the javascript function inside a @section scripts{} and it started working, thank you for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Included javascript inside a @section scripts{} section and it started working,

```
@section scripts{ <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#SelectedReportId').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == '1') {
            $('#IncludePhotos').show();
        } else {
            $('#IncludePhotos').hide();
        }
    });
});</script>}
```

Comment: You do realize that this just shows/hides the checkbox - if the user checked it before selecting an option, it will still post `true`

Comment: check [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1875676.aspx?How+to+hide+an+MVC+drop+down+box+) for more options, hope helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(z => z.SelectedReportId, new SelectList(Model.ReportTypes, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedReportId),new {id="myDropdown"}

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IncludePhotos,new {id="myCheckbox"})

$(function () {
    $('#myDropdown').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var fistVal=$('#myDropdown option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");
        if (value == fistVal) {
            $('#IncludePhotos').show();
        } else {
            $('#IncludePhotos').hide();
        }
    });
});
```